# date_trunc month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract the "month" from the date_contact column. I tried `select  dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, date_contact), 0)
from cohort` and `select cast(date_contact As Date)`. I received result that is same as date from the first method. And for the second method I got error message: `date_contact is not a valid name`.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `MONTH()` function?

Comment: @Osca many of your questions can be answered from the microsoft documentation... I would recommend having a read.

Comment: date_trunc would be from PostgreSQL - question should be "what is the equivalent?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select datepart(mm,date_contact) from cohort
```

aka..

```
select month(date_contact) from cohort
```

or...

```
select datename(mm,date_contact) from cohort
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Just have one more question, I want to add more conditions to it such as select the earliest time from date_contact and group by user_id `select  user_id, datepart(mm,min(date_contact)) as cohort_month
from cohort
group by 1`. However, I got error from `group by`

Comment: use: `... group by user_id` instead of 1

Answer (score 1):

```
select dateadd(day,-(day(getdate())-1),cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your question and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use **[`MONTH()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/month-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function

```
SELECT MONTH(date_contact)
FROM YourTable;
```

Which will return the month number, and if you want to return the month name, then you can use **[`DATENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** function

```
SELECT DATENAME(Month, date_contact)
FROM YourTable;
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), date_contact, 100)
FROM YourTable;
```